# Get the byte size of a string in Netsuite

Tags: file, byte, size, netsuite

I want to know the byte size of a string before create a file . I know the size limit of the file I can create (10 MO) so before to create this file I want to fill it the more possible.

Note : I don't have access to all the JS function on Netsuite

I tried different function :

```
function byteCount(s) {
  return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}

String.byteSize()


function getBinarySize(string) {
  return Buffer.byteLength(string, 'utf8');
} 
Buffer doesn't exist in js Netsuite
```

with theese solutions I got bytessize = 15  but when I create the file it's 76.24 KB

Answer (score 0):

For now I have created a function :

```
function getByteSizeFromString(content) {
      var fileObj = file.create({
        fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
        name: "testsizebyte.txt",
        contents: JSON.stringify(content),
        folder: 456530
      });
      var fileId = fileObj.save()
      var fileObj = file.load({ id: fileId })
      var sizeByte = fileObj.size
      file.delete({ id: fileId });
      return sizeByte
    }
```

I should get 76.24 KB but I get 78,06 KB, for now it's the more precise result I get...